# How to get the latest version of github action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am wondering if there is a reliable way to get the latest version of a GitHub action. I found a suggestion to use the main or master branch, but this does not always work for me. Additionally, some actions have different branch names than main or master.

I have tried to use the actions/checkout@latest action in my GitHub workflow, but it is not working. This is the same syntax that I use to install the latest version of a Node.js package, but it does not seem to work for GitHub actions.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @jessehouwing's answer I thought it would be cool to have a tool for that - [so I built it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gha-check-updates)! Feel free to check it out.
It's very simple and maybe a bit buggy, but it works in all of my repos.
Feel free to submit issues if you encounter any issues.

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no reliable way to achieve this. It's up to the owner of the action to setup tags and branches and though there is guidance on how to do this, it's not enforced. In theory an action owner *could* publish a tag called `latest` and that would then work, but unfortunately, nobody does this.

I have created a project which an Actions' author can include in their repo to verify the tags are setup correctly. It will detect missing tags and situations where the version tags aren't pointing to the right commits.

- [Actions Semver Checker](https://github.com/jessehouwing/actions-semver-checker) - An action to verify your version tags are setup correctly.

The "best" way to stay current is to use Dependabot or RenovateBot to automatically submit a pull-request when a new version of an action is published.

Add a `.github/dependabot.yml` file to the repository:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/" # Location of package manifests
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

Then at least you get a PR whenever a new version is released.